# Razor in-line if statement not working?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I've got an exception throwing at this line, and can't figure out why...maybe someone else can spot it

```
<img src="@{Model.Image != null ? Model.Image.FileName : "";}" width="200px" id="ImagePreview"/>
```

The exception I'm getting is:

```
error CS0201: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You need to use the expression `(`explicit`)` code block style for that expression:

```
<img src="@(Model.Image != null ? Model.Image.FileName : "")" width="200px" id="ImagePreview"/>
```

see the [gu's post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/16/asp-net-mvc-3-implicit-and-explicit-code-nuggets-with-razor.aspx)

Comment: Do not add semi-columns (;) before closing the parenthesis

Comment: This solved my problem of trying to return a literal. I was using @{ }. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Try wrapping it in parenthesis instead of curly brackets:

```
<img src="@(Model.Image != null ? Model.Image.FileName : "")" width="200px" id="ImagePreview"/>
```